# Compute a label's text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm writing a TikZ picture, including nodes that I want to label with letters in a regular polygon. I can write numbers doing e.g. for a pentagon:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node
    foreach \i in {0, 1, ..., 4} at (90 + 72 * \i:2.5cm) [name = \i] {\(\i\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I'd like to label them a, b, ... Yes, I could do it by hand, but it gets tiresome. Besides, naming the nodes for their labels would be extremely nice.

Comment: `\@alph\i`  or `\char\numexpr\`a+\i\relax`

Answer (score 2):

### A (La)TeX solution

As [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657204/compute-a-labels-text#comment1637318_657204) states in his comment, you can use `\@alph` or `\char` to get a letter from an integer number.

The `\@alph` macro is a LaTeX macro that is used by `\alph{<LaTeX counter>}` which is used for example in the `enumerate` environment to count from `a` to `z` (instead of `1` to `26`). Since it has a `@` in its name it needs the [`\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` combo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351) and since you also want to start at `0` → `a` you'll need to add `1` to the actual number.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\alphFromZero[1]{\@alph{\numexpr#1+1\relax}}
\makeatother
```

We could have also implemented this from scratch, too:

```
\newcommand*\alphFromZero[1]{\ifcase#1 a\or b\or …\or z\else ?\fi}
```

The TeX primitive `\char` he states could have been used similarly:

```
\newcommand*\alphFromZero[1]{\char\numexpr`a+#1\relax}
```

(The `` `a `` returns the “value” of the character `a` and we'll just add our integer on it and return a character again.)
However, `\char` doesn't seem to be expandable and thus we can't use it to *name* the node.

### PGF/Ti*k*Z solution

That said, both TikZ and `pgffor` offer their own solution.

#### `pgffor`

`pgffor` can actually iterate over letters and with the `count` option you can have both letter and integer number available in the body of the loop:

```
\tikz % nodes are named amed (a), …, (e)
  \node foreach[count=\i from 0] \letter in {a, ..., e} at (90 + 72 * \i:2.5cm)
    [name = \letter] {\(\letter\)};
```

#### Ti*k*Z

Even more fancy (?) you could use the [`chains` library](https://tikz.dev/library-chains) and its `start chain=<chain name> placed <placing formula>` key with the `placing formula` being

```
at=({90+72*(\tikzchaincount-1)}:2.5cm)}
```

where we can use `\tikzchaincount` to refer to the *i*th node in the chain (it starts at `1` which is why we have to subtract `1` again). Then you can just use `on chain=<chain name>` for the node and it is placed automatically according to the `placing formula`.

And you can still use the `name` key to name the nodes individually. They will be available both as `<chain name>-<i>` (where `<i>` again starts at `1`) and your own name.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\alphFromZero[1]{\@alph{\numexpr#1+1\relax}}
% or:
% \newcommand*\alphFromZero[1]{\ifcase#1 a\or b\or …\or z\else ?\fi}
\makeatother

\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\tikz % nodes are named (a), …, (e)
  \node foreach \i in {0, 1, ..., 4} at (90 + 72 * \i:2.5cm)
    [name = \alphFromZero{\i}] {\(\alphFromZero{\i}\)};

\tikz % nodes are named amed (a), …, (e)
  \node foreach[count=\i from 0] \letter in {a, ..., e} at (90 + 72 * \i:2.5cm)
    [name = \letter] {\(\letter\)};

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  start chain=polygon placed {at=({90+72*(\tikzchaincount-1)}:2.5cm)}]
\node foreach \letter in {a, ..., e}
  [on chain, name = \letter] {\(\letter\)};

 % named (a), …, (e) and (polygon-1), …, (polygon-5)
\draw (polygon-1) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```